# Search the string of a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a function similar to Search that can search within formulas, rather than the displayed cell contents? e.g. being able to find 'myWorksheet' within `='myWorksheet'!$A$1`. I need an actual formula, rather than using Show Formulas.

I can make one in VBA easily enough but curious to know if there's one ready made and my Google-Fu has let me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Excel worksheet function that does that. Both Find() and Search() will evaluate the value of a cell, not its underlying formula.

The Find/Replace command (Ctrl-F or Ctrl-H) has the option to search in formulas, but it will only find the cell with the search term, not the position of the search term within the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Since teylyn has confirmed no built in function exists I created my own which I'll share here in case it's of use to anyone. Place it in a code module of a macro enabled workbook and use it in the same way as Search. It will search the cell formula if it has one or the cell value if not and return a -1 if no match is found:

```
Function SearchFormula(rng As Range, val As String) As Integer

Dim f As String
Dim pos As Integer

f = rng.Formula

If f <> "" Then
    pos = InStr(1, f, val)
    If pos = 0 Then pos = -1
Else
    pos = -1
End If

SearchFormula = pos

End Function
```

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Star, I didn't notice that. Thank you.

Comment: Been there, done that.... I know all about it myself.... The oversight is common I think. They make it small but the sign up, etc. nice and BIG.... LOL